# is there any way to set value for whole application in grails except session and context

Tags: grails

is there any way  to set value for whole application in grails except session and context, By which we can share a value for different user.
in Grails 2.3.7
Please help me.

Comment: How about a property on a Service? Since services by default are singletons there will only be one instance of it and thus one value shared for the entire application. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Or access the grails config via `grailsApplication.config` und put in your `Config.groovy`.

Comment: actually i am getting value from database return value from controller only once. so i don't want to get data each time from database.

Comment: write it into the config in `Bootstrap.groovy` or load it it in your service (`if val==null val=load()`) or put in the ehcache, if you run the plugin or even groovy's `@Lazy` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Controllers and Scopes](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllersAndScopes) chapter.

Available Scopes
Scopes are hash-like objects where you can store variables. The following scopes are available to controllers:

- servletContext - Also known as application scope, this scope lets you
  share state across the entire web application. The servletContext is
  an instance of ServletContext
- session - The session allows associating state with a given user and typically uses cookies to associate a session with a client. The session object is an instance of HttpSession
- request - The request object allows the storage of objects for the current request only. The request object is an instance of HttpServletRequest
- params - Mutable map of incoming request query string or POST parameters
- flash - See below

I think you need the `servletContext` scope.